# React-Native Navigator "Undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigator)" error

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, native, navigator

I am very very knew to React Native (and Stackoverflow) and I have been working on switching screens using the Navigator and I still have not been able to do so after researching for help for two days, so I finally resorted to posting a question. My code gives me an : "Undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigator)" error and this is the code that  I have:

A Navigator class:

```
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen'

export default class Navigation extends Component {
    render() {

    return (

       <Navigator

       initialRoute={{id:"Login"}}

        renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
        {return this.renderScene(route, navigator)}}
      />
    );
}

renderScene(route, navigator) {

    switch(route.id) {

        case "Login":

            return (<LoginScreen {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator}/>);

        case "Home": 

            return (<HomeScreen {...route.passProps} navigator={navigator}/>);

    }
}
}
```

and a LoginButton component in a LoginScreen.js file

```
class LoginButton extends Component {

    render() {
       const routes = [{id:'LoginScreen'},{id:'HomeScreen'}];
        return (

           <View style={{height:50}}>
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <Button style={{backgroundColor: '#eeb211'}} onPress={this.nextScreen.bind(this)} rounded >              Login Next Screen           </Button>
                </Content>
            </Container>
            </View>
        );
    }
   nextScreen() {
     this.props.navigator.push({id:"Home"})

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

```
<Navigator
        style={{ flex:1 }}
        ref={(nav) => { navigator = nav; }}
        initialRoute={{id:"Login"}}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
         {return this.renderScene(route, navigator)}}
      />
```